# OS detection using only open(), read(), write() and close()

Tags: system-calls

I'm writing some code that is going to run under an hypervisor which only allows open, read, write and close syscalls to the external world.

Since part of the code is dependant on the platform it is being run on, I'd like to be able to automatically choose the appropriate code-path at runtime.

What is the most robust way of detecting the operating system using only these syscalls? I'm primarily interested in detecting windows and linux, but osx would be useful too.

Comment: You can compile program as OS-independant? How?..

Comment: It is compiled by the hypervisor just before execution

Comment: I don't think we share meaning of 'hypervisor'. Is it virtual machine/interpreter in your case? That loads some immediate code and executes it?

Comment: It is a software (which I didn't write) which loads my source file, compiles/assembles it and executes it in a restricted environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

uname watches for /proc/sys/kernel/ostype, you could use that.
For windows, it's worse. In theory, you should have C:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll. The problem is, however, that windows installation root is not required to be 'C:\' (although it's very common) - so i highly doubt ordinary open() could be considered reliable.

Comment: Just got a second thought - you could try to open 'NUL' device - it's analog of /dev/null for dos-like OSes, or other special device file name. I think it's guaranteed to be present on windows.

Comment: wow, good idea! I was going with /proc/cpuinfo and C:\\windows\\explorer.exe but if NUL works that would be definitely better (as windows can also be installed in a directory different from "windows" if I recall properly)... I'm going to try this as soon as I can